# Unset pairs if match and never be repeated

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

How can I unset pairs if match?

```
 $pair = array(
                  array('number' => 1000),
                  array('number' => 2000),
                  array('number' => 3000),
                  array('number' => 2000),
                  array('number' => 2000)
                 );
if(sizeof($pair) >= 2) {
    $i = 1;
    $pair_A  = $pair[0];
    while(sizeof($pair) > $i) {
       $pair_B = $pair[$i];
       if($pair_A['number']  == $pair_B['number']) {
           //with match
       } else {
           //no match
       }
       $i++;
       unset($pair_B);
    }
    unset($pair_A);
}
```

The variable `$pair_A` value is always repeated even though I unset it.

I want to have a result which is paired by two:

```
1. No Match = 1000   empty
2. Match with #4 = 2000  2000
3. No Match = 3000   empty
4. Match with #2 = 2000 2000
5. No Match = 2000 empty
```

If match, the corresponding value will also match like #2 and #3 (vice versa matching I guess).

Is  this possible? Please help me I am having trouble in this flow several months already... I hope you can help me.

Comment: Do you want to unset the whole array or just the specific value?

Comment: why don't u use `array_unique()`?

Comment: specific value to avoid multiple values of $pair_A

Comment: @Robert my target is to save them on a database with matching pair e.g. Lakers vs Bulls, Bulls vs Lakers. both of them will have one row to be inserted.

Comment: @Robert array_unique() doesn't work on multi-dimensional arrays

Comment: @Kyra totally agree thanks.

Comment: In `4. Match with #2 = 2000 2000` `#2` should be `#1` am I right?

Comment: @Kyra http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your required output will come here.

```
<?php
$pair = array(
            array('number' => 1000),
            array('number' => 2000),
            array('number' => 3000),
            array('number' => 2000),
            array('number' => 2000)
           );

foreach($pair as $key1=>$array1) {
    $isMatched = false;
    foreach($pair as $key2=>$array2) {
        if($key1!=$key2 && $array1["number"]==$array2["number"]) {
            $key = $key2+1;
            $pair[$key2]["number"] = "";
            $data = "Match with #$key $array1[number] $array2[number]";
            $isMatched = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    $key1++;
    if($isMatched) {
        echo $key1.". ".$data."<br>";   
    } else {
        echo $key1.". No Match = $array1[number] empty"."<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

Output:

```
1. No Match = 1000 empty
2. Match with #4 2000 2000
3. No Match = 3000 empty
4. Match with #2 2000 2000
5. No Match = 2000 empty
```

Comment: hi @Salim. this is the correct format. 2. Match with #4 2000 2000 and 4. Match with #2 2000 2000. if match two records will be paired vice versa.

Comment: Ok, I have said it because array item starts from index 0, so it is corrected now, it is working as you expect.

Comment: thank you very much @Salim it works. what is the purpose of $roosters[$key2]["weight"] = "";? how can also add reputations to your account?

Comment: You can vote to this answer and also can select as best answer.